# Serve external template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to do something like

```
return render_to_response("http://docs.google.com/View?id=bla", args)
```

and serve an external page with django arguments.  Django doesn't like this (it looks for templates in very particular places).

What's the easiest way make this work?  Right now I'm thinking to use urllib to save the page to somewhere locally on my server and then serve with the templates pointing to there.

Note: I'm not looking for anything particularly scalable here, I realize my proposal above is a little dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the template in as a string and [render it yourself](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system).