# Django load template from Google cloud media location

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, google-cloud-storage

I have create a html file and uploaded that in google cloud media location and i am trying to get that html content using below code but I am unable to get template object.

```
from django.template import loader
template_name = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/media/templates/real.html'
template = loader.get_template(template_name)
```

Is there any way to get django template object?

Comment: Well for starter you are not defining `email_template_name`, or you meant that `template_name = 'http://...` _is_ `email_template_name`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serve external template in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031056/serve-external-template-in-django)